# How to delete a file in persistent volume through CLI in Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to delete a file that is stored in persistent volume through CLI. I know the path but not sure how do I through CLI delete the file. 
Reason I want to do it through CLI is that I am automating a certain workflow that requires triggering of a powershell script that runs OpenShift CLI to delete a file in volume and scale down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [Executing Remote Commands](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/executing_remote_commands.html) feature to remove the file as follows.

For example,

```
# oc exec <pod name> -- rm -f /path/to/file.txt
```

I hope it help you.